# Is there software that will let me mirror my iPad and Android Phone to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: android, ios, ubuntu

I would like to be able to mirror my iPad screen and Android Phone's screen to my PC, running Ubuntu 16.04. They are all connected to the same Wifi network. The iPad is running jailbroken iOS 9.3.3, and the Android phone is running rooted Android 4.4 KitKat. Is there anything available for mirroring these devices to my PC? I don't mind using USB or Wireless via Wifi, but I **DO NOT** have Bluetooth. I also don't mind downloading jailbroken or nonjailbroken apps on my iPad or phone.

Also, if I can't do screen mirroring, can I get a setup working similar to Chromecast?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using Teamviewer.

Comment: Try http://www.vysor.io/ for android !

Comment: @JavedAhmed Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that TeamViewer only allowed you to control and see your computer with your mobile device, not view your mobile device on your computer.

Comment: @ComputerGuy TeamViewer quick support allows to connect to any devices. You can even control your mobile device on computer.

Comment: @JavedAhmed I tried using TeamViewer Quick Support, and it worked well for my android phone (not iOS), but I have a few problems: 1. TeamViewer transfers so much data to and from the device, that the actual quality of the phone lags on the computer (WAY too much lag to watch a video or to show someone a game on the big screen), and 2. no sound gets transferred.

Comment: http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-remotely-control-iphone-ipad-from-your-pc-mac-video/

Comment: Go to the above provided link for another solution. It works with android as well.